Does my spouse need a visa to enter Germany if I am German resident (not a citizen) and she is Cyprus resident (not a citizen)?
Both countries are EU countries, but only Germany is Schengen country. If that is possible to enter without visa, why? And for how long?

From the German Embassy, Nicosia

If you hold a residence permit of a EU country (temporary or permanent) which is not a member of the Schengen area (e.g. Cyprus) you need a visa to travel to the Schengen area!


Looks like that, but I have seen mentions that if I would be German citizen then my spouse would not need a visa, is that right?

@igor See eg https://www.bmi.bund.de/SharedDocs/faqs/EN/topics/civil-protection/coronavirus/travel-restrictions-border-control/IV-restrictions-applying-to-air-and-sea-travel-outside-of-europe/what-special-conditions-apply-to-entry-into-germany-by-family-members-who-are-third-country-nationals.html

Thank you so much
